# Optimizing PDF using Python?

Tags: pdf, batch, arcpy

Is there a way to optimize a PDF using Python?

I am exporting hundreds of .mxds  - that works fine with a loop.  But the file size of each is large.  Right now my option is to manually open each and save as optimized.  I would like to run this process monthly, so I need a better solution than that.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for [stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) - there are a few threads there relating to PDF optimization!

Answer (score 4):

On the assumption that you are using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 SP1 (or later), my quick research turned up an ArcGIS Discussion Forum posting entitled  [Help - Large file sizes exporting to PDF using ArcPy](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/17069-Help-Large-file-sizes-exporting-to-PDF-using-ArcPy) that looks to be relevant.

> [At 10.0] SP1, with ExportToPDF and ExportToEPS, we added Adaptive and JPEG
>   compressions. We also added the {jpeg_compression_quality} parameter.

These optional parameters are described in the [ArcGIS Help for ExportToPDF](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s300000027000000).